# scalaでうまくコードが実行できない。

Tags: scala

scalaの開発環境を整え、以下のコードを実行したところ、
エラーが出てうまく実行することが出来ません。
どうすれば、うまく起動できるのでしょうか？

```
object Hello {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello, World!")
  }
}
```

```
"C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.322.6-hotspot\bin\java.exe" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:51940,suspend=y,server=n -javaagent:C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIC2021.3\captureAgent\debugger-agent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.322.6-hotspot\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.322.6-hotspot\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.322.6-hotspot\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.322.6-hotspot\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.322.6-hotspot\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.322.6-hotspot\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.322.6-hotspot\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.322.6-hotspot\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.322.6-hotspot\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.322.6-hotspot\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.322.6-hotspot\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.322.6-hotspot\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.322.6-hotspot\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.322.6-hotspot\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.322.6-hotspot\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.322.6-hotspot\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.322.6-hotspot\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.322.6-hotspot\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\org\scala-lang\scala-library\2.13.8\scala-library-2.13.8.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar" Hello
ターゲット VM に接続しました。アドレス : '127.0.0.1:51940'、トランスポート: 'ソケット'
エラー: メイン・クラスHelloが見つからなかったかロードできませんでした
ターゲット VM から切断されました。アドレス: '127.0.0.1:51940'、トランスポート: 'ソケット'

プロセスは終了コード 1 で終了しました
```

Comment: もしかしたらこの記事とかその参照先が参考になるかも。[yuji38kwmt/!備忘録_Scala.md](https://gist.github.com/yuji38kwmt/be0f6503fd2cbeb24658c449b2c11e26)

Comment: ありがとうございます。お陰様で解決しました。

Comment: 実際には何が原因でどのような対処をして解決したかを自己回答してみてください。

Answer (score 2):

main/scalaのディレクトリ内にscalaのコードを入れていなかったことが問題だったようです。
main/scala内にscalaのコードを入れるとうまく実行できました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]